# ASP.NET HTTPContext Current User Identity is null in Firefox, but not IE11 and Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity works with IE11 and Chrome, but in Firefox when i try to call:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

it returns null. I HAVE enabled cookies in Firefox. 
Any ideas why Firefox can't find current user?

The picture below shows the request

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/594049/how-to-enable-ntlm-for-all-intranet-sites-in-firefox

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked :)